# One timer job not running on one server

Tags: 2013, timer-jobs, incoming-email

We have a multi-server farm and I ran into a strange issue. Incoming emails were not being picked up from the drop folder on our first WFE (I am configuring this for the first time).

I checked the timer jobs and realized that the Microsoft SharePoint Incoming Email timer job was not running on this one WFE only. This is the only server that is configured for incoming emails. Other timer jobs are running as normal on this server. Has anyone run into this issue before?

I also cannot locate any failed instances of this job. From all appearances, it it simply not running on this one server.

Comment: I have tried restarting the timer service from the "Services" application on the server and this has not resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this solution was actually really simple. The timer job is controlled by the server service, which can be found in your central admin console at /_admin/Server.aspx. From there, the feature M SP Foundation Incoming E-mail was inexplicably turned off on this one server. I started the service the timer is running as normal now.